# Remove columns from Biml from RootNode

Tags: ssis, biml

In our Biml files we build a data model in the `rootnode` using the `GetDataSchema()` method. The SSIS packages are based on the tables and columns in the model.

We want to be able to remove a column from the `RootNode` before the packages are compiled. Please let me know how this could be done? Could the `RemoveRootNode(0` method be used. If so. how? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can just [exclude the column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549495/181965) as Cathrine demonstrates if you've already materialized the tables into the Tables collection. The advantage of this approach is that the full schema of your source table is available in case someone does need the excluded columns. The disadvantage of course is that everyone who doesn't need that must repeat your exclusion logic.

The other route would be to handle it when you import your data but prior to making it a Tables collection. Same trick from Cathrine, just in a different place

Assuming you have two files. The first is Environment.biml that looks like

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <Connection Name="CMAdventureWorks2014" ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2014" />
    </Connections>
    <Databases>
        <Database Name="AdventureWorks2014" ConnectionName="CMAdventureWorks2014" />
    </Databases>
</Biml>
```

The second is tableImporter.biml

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <#
    var connection = RootNode.Connections["CMAdventureWorks2014"];
    List<string> schemaList = new List<string>{"Person"};
    var results = connection.GetDatabaseSchema(schemaList, null, ImportOptions.None);

    #>
    <Tables>
        <!-- Always exclude ModifiedDate from our column emission -->
        <# foreach (var table in results.TableNodes){ #>
        <Table Name="<#=table.Name#>" SchemaName="<#= table.Schema #>">
            <Columns>
                <#  
                // Use whatever logic to build exclusion list
                var excludeList = table.Columns.Where(s => s.Name == "ModifiedDate");
                var output = table.Columns.Except(excludeList);
                #>
                <#= output.GetBiml() #>
            </Columns>
        </Table>
        <# } #>
        <#= results.TableNodes.GetBiml() #>
    </Tables>
    <Schemas>
        <#= results.SchemaNodes.GetBiml() #> 
    </Schemas>
</Biml>
```

Now you can inspect the table nodes don't have a reference to ModifiedDate. Since this will depend on tableImporter.biml, we need to specify that it is in a higher tier than Environment.biml (which is tier 0 since it's static biml) and tableImporter.biml (which is tier 1 since it has biml script and no explicit tier defined)

```
<#@ template tier="10" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Annotations>
    <# foreach (var table in RootNode.Tables) {#>
        <Annotation AnnotationType="Documentation" Tag="<#= table.ScopedName #>"><#= table.GetDropAndCreateDdl() #></Annotation>
    <# } #>
    </Annotations>
</Biml>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. After some trial and error I managed to get the result I was after using the RemoveFromParent method.  The following biml file will remove the SpatialLocation from the Address table: <#@ template language="C#" tier="4" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<#
string[,] table = 
                    {
                        {"Address", "SpatialLocation"}
                    };
 
     for (int i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        RootNode.Tables[table[i,0]].Columns[table[i,1]].RemoveFromParent();
    }
#>
</Biml>